# strategy of working with multiple image types and merging into 1 tiff

Tags: c#, pdf, png, jpeg, tiff

I don't have the slightest idea about graphics. I need to build a function that will take a list of different types of files (`pngs`, `bmps`, `jpeg`, `pdf`) and it will create 1 `tiff` file, merging all of the files together.

Can you guide me on the strategy in solving this? ( ...should i first convert every file to a `tiff` and then merge them together? ... should i simply use library XYZ to do this for me because this functionality already exists! should i first compress them somehow together and that will yield a `tiff`?  )

Answer (score 1):

It's doesn't matter what image format you want to use.You are working with bitmaps at the end. load all images and draw(merge) theme on single graphic object and at the end save the file as your own format :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var imageList = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ABC\Desktop\cars");

    Bitmap destnationBitmap = new Bitmap(1000, 300);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(destnationBitmap);
    try
    {
        var drawPoint = new Point(0, 0);

        foreach (string imagePath in imageList)
        {
            var tempBitmap = new Bitmap(imagePath);

            g.DrawImage(tempBitmap, drawPoint);

            drawPoint.X += tempBitmap.Width;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        var tiffVersion = ConverTo(destnationBitmap, ImageFormat.Tiff);
        tiffVersion.Save("TiffVersion.tiff");
        g.Dispose();
    }
}

public static Image ConverTo(Bitmap bitmapImage, ImageFormat pFormat)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    bitmapImage.Save(stream, pFormat);

    return new Bitmap(stream);
}
```